Keeping track of a number between multiple asynchronous execution of a task
Basically I have this number that I use to send a request to a system. Every time I send request it should increase for the next execution. But the requests will be executed as asynchronous task and triggered from multiple places.
I can't send same number multiple times and it doesn't response any error in target system so I can't control if I did so. If I keep the number in database and read for every execution I will either get an error regarding data being tracked or possibly read same number twice (before one task can  increase it) and execute that way. So I am looking for suggestions really.
So far I think only of creating a background service and handling all executions from there, reading number once, executing every request and then updating number in DB for next execution but that would create a delay which I don't like.

This may be an XY problem. Can you explain the problem that you're trying to solve with this number?

For example, maybe it's serving as a unique identifier for the request: if so, is there a reason it has to be a number instead of a string? Is there a reason it needs to be incremental, instead of random? Could a GUID or ULID work instead?

A single static field, accessed via Interlocked.Increment?

I will check interlocked.incremental

It is so the target system can keep track of an operation when I post something but if same identifying number is used before then it just stores posted data instead of doing operation. It is a number because whoever wrote the code deemed so basically. It is incremental because I am one of the many middlewares that connect to this system and everyone gets a specific number range to work with. Like I send from 1 to 1m another will send from 1m to 2m etc

If in-process, then some interlocked increment of a field should be sufficient; if the numbers need to survive between process restarts, or handle multi-mode semantics - then an out-of-process backend database may be useful - redis has an INCR command that does atomic increments if a key
